# Finding SQLiteCpp package with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to find SQLiteCpp using this CMakeLists.txt on Ubuntu 17.04 64bit.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(shule)

find_package(SQLiteCpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SQLITECPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE src/main.cpp)

add_executable(shule ${SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(shule SQLiteCpp)
```

The SQLiteCpp is installed under `'usr/local/lib'` with the name `'libSQLiteCpp.a'` and its CMake scripts, `'SQLiteCppConfig.cmake'` and `'SQLiteCppConfig-noconfig.cmake'`, are installed under 'usr/local/lib/cmake/SQLiteCpp'. The include files are installed under 'usr/local/include/SQLiteCpp'`. I'm trying to compile the following simple file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <SQLiteCpp.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Database" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error message SQLiteCpp.h: No such file or directory #include . What am I missing?

Comment: Try `#include <SQLiteCpp/SQLiteCpp.h>`

Comment: Aren't all the includes for SQLiteCPP nested, so you have to include <SQLiteCPP/SQLiteCPP.h>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your header file is located in `usr/local/include/SQLiteCpp`, most likely `usr/local/include` is in your `$PATH`. Make sure to include the subdirectory.

`#include <SQLiteCpp/SQLiteCpp.h>`

Comment: Also, you should use the provided CMAKE variables

`target_link_libraries(shule ${SQLITECPP_LIBRARY})`